# Prove a path between ordered pairs with rational and irrational numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let S be the collection of ordered pairs (x, y) in [0, 1] × [0, 1] such that either x or y is irrational.
Prove or disprove that for any two distinct ordered pairs in S, we can find a path in S connecting the two points.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCuJY.png)

I was looking at the solution but I have no idea why they use $\sqrt2/2$ to prove this... Could someone explain it or is there any other way to prove this more efficiently?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit the picture's description... If you click "enter image description here" you can see the picture of the solution.

Comment: Actually, the complement of any countable set in the plane is path connected.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. In fact, you can use any irrational number to get the path. What we are essentially doing is that we are ensuring one of the coordinate always remains irrational so that our path does not go "outside" the set. Indeed, if we use any other irrational number in $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, we will still get a path. I suggest that to understand the proof better, you should draw pictures of what is being done in the proof. It will be much easier to grasp the idea and construct similar proofs in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so helpful!

Comment: We can't use $\pi$ or $e$ because they are greater than $1$ and outside the set, but we could use $\frac \pi 4$ or $\frac e3$.

Comment: Yes. For a moment I thought it was a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah that make sense. Thank you guys :).